Jira board Dashboard
I am trying to create a Dashboard for my sprint jira board.The thing is I started creating it but with some gadgets I couldn't make the data related to the current sprint only.
Example:
my current Dashboard that contains the status to all the project sprints tickets
I tried to choose many gadgets but when you try to configure it's always related to all the tickets no to the current sprint.
Thanks for guidance.
How to create a jira dashboard for my current sprint only

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

sorry I did not use code,I just created a dashboard from jira options then I couldn't configure the gadgets with the current sprint :( that's why I asked if this is possible
